# how to predict jvm garbage collection

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, prediction

I'm working on a critical application written in java and it should avoid 'stop the world garbage collection' effects.
I'm looking for a solution that can predict long pauses due to full gc. is it possible?

Comment: If there are times a GC is accpetable, you can always try calling `System.gc()`. When this call returns, it’s unlikely that a new GC will happen in the near future.

Comment: This question is not about statistical prediction, so the 'prediction' tag is probably misplaced.

Comment: @Ole V.V. `gc()` can easily not happen or be disabled. "Near future" is an amorphous term, and likelihood of a new GC is entirely dependent on specifics of the OP's system, its runtime profile, and its bugs, about which we know nothing. So we cannot yet responsibly assert anything about the effect `gc()` would have.

Comment: The common approach for latency-sensitive applications is not attempting to predict pauses but to measure and then reduce them.

Comment: @LewBloch Sure, GC can be disabled, but then, there was someone having disabled it. This is easy to avoid on your own server. You can test it and if it works, you *can* rely on it. That said, changes are that there are much better solutions.

Comment: The system is free to disregard `gc` calls even if they are not specifically disabled, plus they incur major GC instead of just minor, so you really cannot rely on them.

Answer (score 5):

The best thing you can do is to either reduce allocations and/or use a pause less GC like Azul's.  This will make GCs easier to manage.

If you reduce allocations enough in key sections (identified using metrics e.g. a profiler like JMC/JFR) you can run all day without a full collection, or in extreme cases, all day without a minor collection.

You can monitor how full the tenured space is and see if it is filling up (there are other causes of full GC but this is the most common)

Comment: "Reduce allocations" could significantly worsen GC performance, because most things people do to reduce allocations cause objects to live until they're promoted to "tenured". It is not advice to be followed naïvely. Better advice is to allocate references at the narrowest scope the algorithms permit so that young-generation GCs are the rule, and so that objects are released as early as possible to avoid memory leaks (packratting). Also, design objects to require minimal initialization. Follow the best inherent program logic to get the best GC profile.

Comment: @LewBloch allocating objects involve work which should often be avoided. Ideally escape analysis can eliminate allocation so I would avoid optimising code the jit can optimise for you ie only remove actual allocations at runtime instead of where you think allocations occur. You do want to avoid objects dying in tenured space though I have seen this very rarely especially if you can have much few minor collections.

Comment: Allocating objects takes next to no time, perhaps ten or twelve machine instructions. The memory system guarantees that the JVM merely has to store a pointer and bump up the top-of-heap marker. What takes time is initialization. My suggestion accounted for that, and like yours, advocates avoiding having objects reach the tenured generation. Most objects should be left to die young.

Comment: @LewBloch the memory pressure created by allocation reduces cache efficiency and slows down every memory access, you can improve the performance of an application by 2-5x just by reducing allocations in critical sections.

Comment: Perhaps. Perhaps not. It depends on the runtime characteristics of the program. This can only be determined by actual measurement in the real world. A priori "optimization" of this nature is unlikely to produce useful improvement. But regardless, you have to allocate necessary objects for the application. Keeping lifetimes short reduces the number of such objects in memory at a time, that helps with cache issues. Keeping objects unto the tenured generation causes issues that swamp the tiny gains of microoptimizations.

Comment: @LewBloch I agree that changing your code in an unfocused way is likely to do as much harm as good in terms of performance but adding complexity **will** make maintenance harder. It only makes sense to optimise code driven by metrics e.g. a profiler like jfr.

Answer (score 2):

Well that's not possibile at all. I think the best way to avoid that "stop the world" garbage collection is minimizing the life of objects. Small runs.

BTW, you need to try different solutions and profile them.

Comment: Great advice, and allows young-generation GCs to dominate, where allocation is nearly free and deallocation completely free, and ensures that live-object copies are as small as possible.

Answer (score 0):

why not force regularly GC, with a frequency depending on memory usage for example ?

Comment: Because you can't?